# cron command to run every 12 hours

Tags: unix, cron

I need unix cron command to run every 12 hours.

I have 500+ sub blogs in my server.

This is the file i want to run every 12 hours

```
http://*.mysite.com/somedir/index.php
```

Where * is my subdomain of my blogs.

I need cron command for all blogs. 
Is it possible to run all of them with single command?
OR do i have to create command for each blog?

Comment: What don't you understand: the format of `crontab` or how to access/run a PHP script?

Comment: Do you have list of sites somewhere? (to what should the '*' expand?)

Comment: do you want to run the script locally, or call it from a different machine? If you have it locally you could easily create one command. Calling a curl or wget on each page one by one will prove a bit harder.

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes i want the format of crontab for every 12 hours. I don't want to run all 500+ blog script at a time. For example give me the code to run 1AM and 1PM. Thanks

Comment: @JensTimmerman I'm not sure what you mean local. I have a hosting account in namecheap. That is where my files are stored

Comment: Be specific over the requrement, what is that you are trying to run in the cronjob regarding those blogs?

Comment: @user1091558 so you don't have access to the machine, you can only upload documents, and  you want to run a cron on your own unix machine (not hosting the sites)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

A crontab file has five fields for specifying day , date and time followed by the command to be run at that interval.

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

`*` in the value field above means all legal values as in braces for that column.

You could use `0 1,13 * * *` which means for every 1AM and 1PM.

```
0 1,13 * * * rm /var/www/*/somedir/index.php > /home/someuser/cronlogs/some.log 2>&1
```

where `*` can be replaced by different domain names.

Comment: This is the best answer since it shows you how to do this with arbitrary hours, not just 12PM / 12AM

Comment: explain me rm in this string? :)

Comment: Note that you can also define a minute, e.g. "47 1,13 * * *" which means "every 1:47am and 1:47pm". This can be helpful to reduce loads on your server; instead of running all crons at the 0th minute of each hour, space them out

Answer (score 34):

I think the right way is -> `1 */12 * * *` (*actually, any number in the minute position will do the trick.*)

If you set -> `* */12 * * *` it will be executed every minute at 12h and again at 24h.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming your sites live in /var/www/sitename and you have the php shell installed in /usr/bin/php you can easily create a cron job that runs all those files.

run

> crontab -e

and add this line

```
42 */12 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/*/somedir/index.php  >> ~/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

The * here in /var/www/*/somedir is just a wildcart. This means it will catch every directory in your /var/ww folder.

f.ex:

```
[jens@localhost ~]$ ls -l temp
total 28
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jens jens 1641 Feb 21 16:12 somefile.py
drwxrwxr-x. 2 jens jens 4096 Feb 22 15:10 test
drwxrwxr-x. 2 jens jens 4096 Feb 22 15:10 test2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 jens jens 4096 Feb 22 15:10 test3
drwxr-xr-x. 8 jens jens 4096 Jan 27 10:21 emptydir
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jens jens  548 Jan 27 16:15 Unsaved Document 1

[jens@localhost ~]$ ls temp/*/testfile.php 
temp/test2/testfile.php  temp/test3/testfile.php  temp/test/testfile.php
```

As you can see, this returns the testfile.php in each subfolder of temp, namely folder test, test2 and test3.
Emptydir is also a folder, but since it has no testfile.php in it, nothing willhappen with it.

If your directory structure is arbitrarily deep you can use [**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176590/what-do-double-asterisk-wildcards-mean)

e.g.
`42 */12 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/**/index.php  >> ~/cronjob.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hi i'm not sure what `*` mean in this line `/var/www/*/somedir/index.php`  You want me to use the command as it is or i have to replace it with my subdomains?

Comment: @user1091558: that is what I asked you under the OT. Do you have a list of sites (or a list of scripts)?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I'm using wordpress multisite. I have 500+ blogs under one installation. So i have only list of sites

Comment: Quick question about your example */12.  Would `4/12` in the hour field match both 4am and 4pm?

Comment: @marcos It's better to just use '4,16' if this is the behaviour you want.

Comment: wouldn't you need to change the first * to a number (such as 0). i think this runs every minute for every hour that it is allowed to run (which is two hours a day of course). so that's 120 times run a day?

Comment: @celwell no, it this context * stands for a range from beginning to end.

Comment: @Emirikol you're right that * is just a shorthand for 0-59, which is, in turn, a shorthand for a long list of 0,1,2,...,59. Which still means that celwell is right.

Comment: my bad, I was looking at the second * in the expression instead of the first one.

Answer (score 7):

Use "*/12" to mean "every 12 hours."

Answer (score 6):

You need some kind of master-script (called by cron), which expands the list of sites, and calls "/usr/bin/php /var/www/*/somedir/index.php", whith the '*' replaced by a list entry. This can be done in a shellscript, a perl or python script, or maybe even a php script. For sh this could be: (untested)

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/subdir/for/cron

LIST="a b c d e f g h i j k l m o p q r s t u v w x y z"

for x in $LIST; do
   /usr/bin/php /var/www/${x}/somedir/index.php 2>$1 > /tmp/${x}.log
done
```

If it is inconvenient to have the list hardcoded like this, there are other methods:
`backticks`, or `read < file_with_all_the_names_in_it`

Answer (score 4):

`0 */12 * * *` means "At minute 0 past every 12th hour."

Check out https://crontab.guru for a nice calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Write command in console

> ```
> crontab -e
> ```

edit with editor (I like nano)

add line

> 0 1,13 * * * php /home/catalog/public_html/crons/index.php

close with

> press ctrl + x

press y then press enter
done :)

Check if saved with

> crontab -l

command

if you want to test if it will work test just running it manualy with

> php /home/catalog/public_html/crons/index.php

command

Answer (score -1):

Use this  it will Run after each 12 hour 
* */12 * * *   php  /var/www/"Your domain"/cronfile.php

Comment: This should be 0 */12 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/somedir/index.php. If you were to use an asterisk in the first position, it would run every minute of every 12th hour.

Answer (score -1):

`->cron('0 */12 * * *');`

This cron will run the scheduler at every 12 hours.