# What is the ** glob character?

Tags: gulp, glob

I have this path in my react gulpfile:

```javascript
var path = {
  HTML: 'src/index.html',
  ALL: ['src/js/*.js', 'src/js/**/*.js', 'src/index.html'],
  JS: ['src/js/*.js', 'src/js/**/*.js'],
  MINIFIED_OUT: 'build.min.js',
  DEST_SRC: 'dist/src',
  DEST_BUILD: 'dist/build',
  DEST: 'dist'
};
```

What is the double glob character?

I know what the single glob is... but what is the double?
[single glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It's almost the same as the single asterisk but may consist of *multiple* directory levels.

In other words, while `/x/*/y` will match entries like:

```
/x/a/y
/x/b/y
```

and so on (with only one directory level in the wildcard section), the double asterisk `/x/**/y` will *also* match things like:

```
/x/any/number/of/levels/y
```

with the concept of "any number of levels" also including zero (in other words, `/x/**/y` will match `/x/y` as one of its choices).

---

As an aside, as much as I hate to credit the mainframe with *anything,* I believe this has been used since the earlist days of MVS to allow selection of datasets at multiple levels :-)

Comment: This makes no sense. If * denotes 0 or more characters, then that pattern could potentially match /x//y, which is nonsensical. What you're really saying is "any number of characters, followed by any number of characters". Isn't that just... oh, I don't know... *any number of characters*???

Comment: @AleksandrH, no, this isn't a regex in the normal sense: there's no matching of *characters,* only directory names. This is *specifically* for hierarchical file systems. On your first point, if empty directory names were allowed, `/x//y` would be perfectly valid. I've never seen a file system that allows this however. On your second point, the `*` means match "any directory name, *one level only"* (so won't go beyond the next `/` divider) while `**` means "match *any number of levels* with any directory name at each level" (can cross over as many `/` dividers as needed).

Comment: It's worth noting that for `/x/**/y/`, `/x/y/` is also included, which is neat.

Comment: @YassineImounachen yes. There are more non-obvious nuances. For the visually inclined, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66744400/8910547

Answer (score 37):

`**` matches any character *including* a forward-slash `/`
`*` matches any character *except* a forward-slash (to match just the file or directory name)

Comment: This is close but not perfect. `x/**` will match `x`. See https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Globstar/lib/File/Globstar.pod

Comment: For people who found this discussion while looking for info on the python glob function: the glob function is working as you describe. "/x/**/y" doesn't match "/x/y"

Answer (score 29):

It's usually used to indicate any number of subdirectories. So

```
src/js/**/*.js
```

Would match

```
src/js/files/*.js
src/js/more-files/*.js

etc
etc
```

Comment: A single asterisk would also match your examples. I think you meant to include an additional sub-subdirectory to your second example.

Comment: @SimonEast like this? src/js/files/controllers/user.js, src/js/files/models/foo/var.js

Comment: @anyone ¿this won't match js files inside src/js/?

Comment: @Victor, I just tried this and yes: JS files in `src/js/` **are** matched, e.g. `src/js/main.js`

Comment: This doesn't cover all cases. The accepted answer does.

Answer (score 6):

> Like Grunt, the double ** is saying, "Look in all the subfolders
>   within js and for all of the .js files."

You can actually refer here for the same:

https://www.codefellows.org/blog/quick-intro-to-gulp-js