# regexr in json file

Tags: json

I'm reading the article [Debugging ES6 in Visual Studio Code](https://medium.com/@drcallaway/debugging-es6-in-visual-studio-code-4444db797954) and find a syntax in `launch.json` file that I don't quite understand.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch App.js",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.js",
      "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/.compiled/**/*.js" ]
    }
}
```

```
 "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/.compiled/**/*.js" ]
```

What does the `**` (two stars) represent? Also, does `*.js` match `filname.js.map` beside matching `filename.js`? I am not sure if this kind of pattern relates to regexr.

Comment: That looks more like a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) than regex. Either way, it has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: `*.js` will match `filename.js` but it should not match `filename.js.map` It is not a regular expression.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a regex *(because dot in ".js" does not look like it matches any character)*.

This is kind of fancy wildcard for a filename:

1. `${workspaceRoot}` - some environmental variable
2. `/.compiled` - exact name of folder (e.g. for generated code)
3. `/**` - any set of nested folders
4. `/*.js` - any file with `js` extension at path specified before

> Also, does *.js match filname.js.map beside matching filename.js?

I assume that it does not, only `filename.js`.

Answer (score 1):

the ** (double-glob) means that it will search in any number of subdirectories. For example,

a/**/b

will match

a/a/b

a/c/b

a/c/a/b

and so on.