# Gulp watch not watching

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am having some issues with my gulpfile configuration when I edit main.scss, gulp watch is running in the terminal but it does not detect the changes made in main.scss, but when I run gulp.sass, it detects the changes, I have looked through some of the other "gulp watch issues" and I still can't find a fix, what am I doing wrong? Let me know if it needs to be more clear

```
Folder directory - 
weather-app
 ---node_modules
 ---public
    ---css
        ---main.css
    ---js
        ---main.js
 ---index.html
 ---src
    ---sass
        ---main.scss
        ---mobile.scss
    ---js
        ---main.js
 ---gulpfile.js
 ---package-lock.json
 ---package.json
```

```js
const gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  uglifyCss = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
  concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');


gulp.task('sass', () => {
  gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(uglifyCss({
      'uglyComments': true
    }))
    .pipe(concatCss('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
})

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);



gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['watch'])
})
```

Comment: What does the folder structure look like. Where does the `main.scss` sit in the directory structure?

Answer (score 2):

gulp.watch mustn't be a returned value.
Don't forget to use the **double asterisk** as well, for targeting any **.scss** file inside your **sass** folder.

[About the ** glob character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character)

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['watch'])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

change the gulp watch line to 
`gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['watch'])`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglifyCss = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');


gulp.task('sass', () => {
    gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
        // gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concatCss('main.css'))
        .pipe(uglifyCss({
            'uglyComments': true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))

})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']); //i changed 'sass' to 'watch'



gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
})
```

thanks, everyone for contributing, I fixed it, it was a minor error I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong line:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

So you must call watch as default task. So this is solution:

```
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

AND this line change from

```
 gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['watch'])
```

to

```
 gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['sass'])
```

That's all. :)