# How File matching patterns exactly works using Asterisk?

Tags: c#, file, pattern-matching, matching

I have below files:

```
C:\files\file1.dll
C:\files\file2.dll
C:\files\sample\sample1.dll
c:\files\sample\sample2.dll
c:\files\book\book1.dll
c:\files\book\book2.dll
c:\files\book\comic\comic1.dll
c:\files\book\comic\comic2.dll
```

pattern 1 is `*\*.dll`, pattern 2 is `*\comic\*.dll` and pattern 3 is `book\*\*.dll`. What files should match `pattern1`, `pattern2` and `pattern3`

Comment: sorry, pattern1 is *\\*.dll and pattern 3 is book\\*\\*.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern should match everything in wildcard matching. You are basically saying.

Contains `\` and ends with `.dll`

The second one should match the last two.

Contains `\comic\` and ends with `.dll`

The last one should match nothing.

Starts with `book\` contains `\` and ends with `.dll`

This of course is for pattern matching as described here [Matching strings with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299671/matching-strings-with-wildcard) and not regular expressions.

In the `glob` world, it's not exactly that:

> ** matches any character including a forward-slash /
>
> * matches any character except a forward-slash (to match just the file or directory name)

So think about it this way. The first pattern will only match the first and the second. By using the double ** you effectively say, I also care about subdirectories.

excellent explanation with more examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character)

Comment: Thanks for swift reply, but what i thought is * means all files in specified source folder. ** means all files in the specified source folder and all files in all sub-folders as per [copy files task azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). So by using azure copy task doesn't pattern1 matches - file1.dll, file2.dll,sample1.dll, sample2.dll, book1.dll and book2.dll? Pattern 3 matches - book1.dll, book2.dll, comic1.dll, comic2.dll

Comment: So you are trying to match using http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html. Ok, now that I know what you are trying to achieve I might help some more.

Comment: Thanks, understood a little bit. But how C:\files\\*\\*.dll pattern work for above files?

Comment: It should return the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th rows. Not the first or the last two.

Comment: Super, And last doubt - c:\files\\**\\*.dll pattern matches all files , but why c:\files\\*\\*.dll pattern does not match 1 to 6 rows but matches only 3 to 6 rows

Comment: because the double asterisk, contains folders and the single asterisk does not.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, and also i understood the concept