# How to enable Intellisense for Python in VS Code but Disable Linting by Pylance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381297/cant-fully-disable-python-linting-pylance-vscode?newreg=f7a3fd7793324dc588177c29924b2eb8)

The above post asks how to disable linting in VS Code by Pylance. This proposed setting works:

```json
"python.languageServer": "None"
```

But it also disables features like **Intellisense** and **Go to Definition**. I want to keep those features working and disable the automatic linting done by Pylance as I'm actively writing out code. It's very distracting.

Note that setting `"python.linting.enabled": false` doesn't work; Pylance still points out "problems" in code the moment I stop typing.

I also don't want to disable linting entirely, I just want to have more control over when my files are linted (like getting warnings after saving). I'm also using other programs like **flake8** and **bandit** which provide the functionality I need and can be shut off until I'm ready to check my code.

**Update:**

I found a way to disable specific Pylance warnings by referencing [this document](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules) in pylance-release. Setting a rule to **none** disables warnings for that rule. I added the following to my **settings.json:**

```json
   "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportUnboundVariable": "none",
        "reportUndefinedVariable": "none",
        "reportMissingImports": "none",
        "reportMissingModuleSource": "none",
    }
```

I did not however find a way to disable syntax error warnings.

Answer (score -1):

Open the command palette using `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type in linting. You should have 2 options[image: 1]
It's pretty self explanatory from here.

Comment: That does work for other linting programs (flake8 for example), but as I explained in my post disabling linting does not disable linting by Pylance.