# What does "*.+(js|jsx)" mean in package.json?

Tags: javascript, eslint, glob, prettier

I'm setting up **ESLint** and **Prettier** for my `Next.js` Project. I have followed one of the articles [this one](https://xenox.dev/setting-up-eslint-and-prettier-for-next-js-project/).

Here is my `package.json` file (partial) so far:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint '*/**/*.{js,jsx}' --fix"
    ]
  }
```

Although I have copied and pasted but couldn't able to understand that `*.{js,jsx}` & `*/**/*.{js,jsx}` what actually these patterns mean? In addition: `*.+(js|jsx)` want to know about this pattern.

Comment: `*.+(js|jsx)` seems to be part of a regular expression. Glob is what shells implement for file path matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's regex-like called a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), so it knows which files it should apply the command to.

- `*` any character
- `.` a dot
- `{js,jsx}` Either 'js' or 'jsx'
- `**` [may consist of multiple directory levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character)

*foo.js* matches that
*bar.php* does not.

The second one is the actual JS lint command. It basically means that everthing that matches that structure gets `eslint`.

You could also set `"eslint 'src/javascript/*.{js,jsx}' --fix"` for example, if that is the only directory you want it to check it, leaving all other JS files alone.

Comment: It's not a regex because if it was `*` would be a quantifier for zero to infinity, `.` would be any character, and  `{js,jsx}` would not be valid, as it's supposed to be a quantifier but doesn't have numbers for min and max.

Comment: It's a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (or maybe some "extended form" or it).

Comment: Wanted to keep it simple, but i suppose I should use the correct term :)