# Timelapse from image files in subfolders using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, timelapse

Is it possible to search for image files in subfolders using FFMPEG? I'm creating a time lapse video file from jpegs and they are located in subfolders (for each recorded day).

Here is my current code, which will work if I run it in the folder with the image files, but it will not work if I try to run it on the parent folder (the folder containing the subfolders).

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out3.mp4
```

Edit: I also tried this after the suggestion from @kesh

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -pattern_type glob -i '**/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out3.mp4
```

What happens with that one is that it will indeed find the files in the subfolder but it only seems to encode the contents of the first subfolder.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604736/4516027) help?

Comment: It did indeed help! Edit: I need to make an answer out of this, since the code doesn't format correctly in the comment.

Comment: After testing some more I have to unfortunately conclude that simply adding two asterisks and a forward slash in the file path doesn't really work. What happens is that it will indeed find the files but it only seems to encode the contents of the first subfolder.

Comment: Just curious how does it make sure the order is correct when using the wildcards?