# tsconfig.json include glob wildcards - any difference between include "src" and include "src/**/*"?

Tags: typescript, wildcard, glob, tsconfig

Any difference between these 2 in `tsconfig.json`?

`"include": ["src"]`

`"include": ["src/**/*"]`

Every example I can find uses the second version, but I'm seeing in my repo that there is no difference. Is there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \*\* glob character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character)

Comment: If you aren't observing any behavioral difference, then it's because you don't have any candidate compilation files in nested directories.

Comment: I wish they have documented it... \
There are so many different glob syntax implemented in different ways, \
eg: tsconfig.json in Typescript, launch.json in vscode, Linux, other lib config file... \
eg: `src` `**/src` `**/src/**` `**/src/**/*` `./src` `/src` `src/` ..., they may all mean the same thing, or different thing, or just error. \
And there is no way to test the actual result, until you actually run the code & may find something breaks...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049111/tsconfig-json-include-glob-wildcards-any-difference-between-include-src-and?noredirect=1#comment136745886_76049111) @Nor.Z [`typescript` v5.3.2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.3.2/package.json#L70) uses [`glob` v8.1.0](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/tree/v8.1.0).

Comment: @jsejcksn It would be better if ts could have documented that, though, I think they modified the implementation base on `"glob": "^8.1.0",`? eg: `"/src/**/*"` (to specify path from the root) doesnt work (or its vscode's problem... but anyways).

Comment: @jsejcksn Actually, > This does not use the glob module, as TypeScript runs in more host environments than just NodeJS, and this would need to interoperate with the language service host. -- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5980

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049111/tsconfig-json-include-glob-wildcards-any-difference-between-include-src-and?noredirect=1#comment136746969_76049111) @Nor.Z Oh, I now see the custom implementation in [`src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.3.2/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts). I guess that's your answer.

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, that is the answer. (though its very long..) (Thanks for your effort.)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> `include`
> Specifies an array of **filenames** or patterns to include in the program.
> These f**ilenames** are resolved relative to the directory containing the tsconfig.json file.

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include

So, according to the docs it is an array of **files** and not **files or directories**.

Even **if** it also works for directories because of some undocumented way of using that value by the compiler (which I am not even sure it does, see the comments to you question) I would not use just the directory name to save five characters, because if you are using an undocumented functionality then you always risk that some new version will go out that removes this undocumented functionality, technically not even being a breaking change.

In other words, the shorter version may work, but if it is not compatible with the official documentation then it should not be relied upon in the long term.

Comment: The doc just unclear. \
eg: The `exclude` uses `node_modules` as default. \
Also I think `directory` is count as `file` in Linux... \
Also, this doesnt talks about `src` is: at root; or at relative path; or at any path like `**/src`. \
 
Slightly more info in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5980 , but still not detailed...