# How to use tail -f recursively on a directory and its sub-directories?

Tags: shell, unix, tail

I am trying to use tail utility in linux to monitor the logs present under nested directories.
I tried using `tail -f /var/log/**/*` but this only go till direct child of `log` directory. It does not dig beyond one level.
Basically I am trying to tail all the application logs in docker container and pass them to /proc/1/fd/1, so that they appear under docker logs.

Comment: Which shell exactly? Modern Bash will recurse subdirectories with `**` so you must be using something else.

Comment: Its bash. @tripleee

Comment: Some older version then? Which version?

Comment: It's 4.3.48(1)-release @tripleee

Comment: And are you sure? Many people are surprised to learn that `/bin/sh` might not be Bash at all.

Comment: echo $0 shows bash and echo $SHELL shows /sbin/nologin. I am running this inside my docker container.

Comment: tail(1) can’t do this.  You need a dedicated tool capable of reading multiple files at once.  Using a `docker run -v` option to mount a host directory over the container’s log directory is probably easier and would let you read the log files after the fact.

Comment: @DavidMaze GNU `tail` will happily run with or without `-f` on any number of files you can fit into `ARG_MAX` (though if all of them are growing it will be hard to keep up).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable

```
 shopt -s globstar
```

if it is disabled in your shell.

With this setting enabled, Bash will recurse directories with `**`.

This is not a feature of Docker or `tail`, it is a feature of your shell.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176590/what-do-double-asterisk-wildcards-mean

Comment: Thanks @tripleee , this shopt did the work for me. It was disabled.

Comment: If I wish to get the file name as well where process is tailing on in the output, what could be done for that?

Comment: When you run `tail -f` on multiple files, it tells you which one it's reading from when it switches from one to another. If that's unacceptable, I guess you need to run a separate process for each file and prefix each line with the file name, or something. There are dedicated tools like `multitail` which do this sort of thing (not sure what the exact feature set of that specific one is, just that it's popular).

Comment: I made it work by below command
`tail -f -v <logname> | awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a":"$0}'`