# Tailwind laravel pagination doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

So, I'm creating a project using laravel and tailwind.
After using the paginate() method and then this code in the view

```
@if ($posts->count())
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <a class="font-bold" href="">{{ $post->user->name }}</a> <span
                            class="text-gray-600 text-sm">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>

                        <p class="mb-2">{{ $post->description }}</p>
                    </div>

                @endforeach
                {{ $posts->links() }} (this line to create the link to other pages is not working properly)
            @else
                <p>There are no posts</p>
            @endif
```

The pagination design was a little bizarre. Going to the next and previous page is working correctly.
[image: Website]

Comment: are you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: Using {{ $posts->links('pagination::semantic-ui') }} things get better, but i don't have the arrows while using it.

Comment: So it's the design that's screwed up, pagination itself works? Did you inspect the pagination elements? Do they have Tailwind classes applied?

Comment: i've tried npm run dev and npm run watch and both didn't change anything

Comment: The pagination works. The foreach has tailwind classes

Comment: in your enviroment you have the entire tailwind css file included or a purged version of it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Wasn't able to fix it but found a workaround by using:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

As described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

The outputted resources/views/vendor/pagination/tailwind.blade.php file did have the correct css and looked good.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `npm i tailwindcss-plugins -D`

Then register the plugin in your tailwind configuration.

```
plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-plugins/pagination')({
        /* ... */
    }),
],
```

And then you can use this in your blade:

`{{ $items->links() }}`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and was able to solve it by using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you publish the vendor view with either:

`artisan vendor:publish`

and selecting the 'laravel-pagination' tag or using the command argument:

`artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

That the resulting published view files are included in your `tailwind.config.js`.

For example:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
        "./resources/**/*.vue",
        "./resources/views/vendor/pagination/*.blade.php",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

I found that without this, the tailwind styles weren't applied. However, I am not sure why since the `./resources/**/*.blade.php` pattern should have picked them up from what I have read.

E.G: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985520/5108242)

> Double Asterisk (`**`) matches zero or more characters across multiple segments. It is used for globbing files that are in nested directories.

> Example: `Tests/**/*.js`

> Here, the file selecting will be restricted to the `Tests` directory. The glob will match the files such as `Tests/HelloWorld.js`, `Tests/UI/HelloWorld.js`, `Tests/UI/Feature1/HelloWorld.js`.

Answer (score 0):

How to use tailwind with laravel and make it work is written in the official documentation - [read](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel#mix)!

**Additionally!** *Tailwind* in *Laravel* is used for pagination by default. If you need to change the styles used, for example, to *Bootstrap*, you can easily do this by writing in next code:

*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*

```
// ...
public function boot(): void
{
    \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
}
// ...
```

[official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#using-bootstrap)