# Does double asterisk include the current directory?

Tags: bash, glob

The following question asks [What do double-asterisk (**) wildcards mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176590/what-do-double-asterisk-wildcards-mean)

Many answers there indicate that `**` includes the current directory as well as sub-directories.

However, when I test this in a bash console it only appears to list files from sub-directories.
The following both list only sub-directory files

```
$ find **/*.md
docs/architecture.md
docs/autodetect.md
# ...

$ ls -d **/*.md
docs/architecture.md
docs/autodetect.md
# ...
```

Despite there being .md files in the current directory

```
$ ls -d *.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md  SECURITY.md
```

Am I misunderstanding the answers to the referenced question, or am I testing the pattern incorrectly?

How can I be sure a command in a script operates on files in both the current directory and sub-directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) option needs to be turned on to enable special interpretation of `**/`. Otherwise, it is just two `*` globs in a row which won't match the current directory.

> When the `globstar` shell option is enabled, and `*` is used in a filename expansion context, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match only directories and subdirectories.

Here is the default behavior (`shopt -u globstar`):

```
$ ls **/*.md
docs/architecture.md  docs/autodetect.md
```

And here is what you get when it's set (`shopt -s globstar`):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ls **/*.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md  SECURITY.md  docs/architecture.md  docs/autodetect.md
```