# Shell script to delete particular files

Tags: linux, shell, tcl

I have a multiple layers of folder example a(b(c(d(u,v))))

Here in every level there is a folder `sync`, for example in every directory `sync` folder is present i.e `a/sync`, `a/b/sync` and so on.

I am looking to write a shell or tcl script which will go in every folder and delete the particular file(sync).

Can anyone guide me?
Thanks
Good day

Comment: Is `sync` a regular file or a directory?  If the former, you probably want one of:`find a -name sync -delete` or `find a -name sync -exec rm {} \;` or `find a -name sync -exec rm -rf {} +` The last option (`rm -rf`) can also be used if `sync` is a directory.

Comment: its a .SYNC its hidden

Comment: So use `find a -name .sync ...`. It is only "hidden" in the sense that some tools by default do not display names that begin with `.`.  That doesn't really change anything significant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rmdir ./**/.sync`.
This will search recursive in the current directory for every directory called `sync` and delete it.

For use of the double asterisk also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985520/11688567)

Note that this will only delete directories(folders) and if it's not empty.

To remove the directories with all files in it, use `rm -r ./**/.sync`

Comment: its a .SYNC so hiddne , but it has one txt file , so i guess it woww be also removed.

Comment: Updated the answer for usage  with `.sync`-directories, but no, `rmdir` will not delete the directory if there are files inside

Answer (score 0):

Find and remove...

```bash
find . -type d -name sync -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Explanations:

- `.`: search for current directory
- `-type d`: search for directories only
- `-name sync`: search for file/directory named "`sync`"
- `-exec ...`: execute this command on each file/directory found

  - `rm -rf`: remove file and directories named ...
  - `{}`: is replaced by each file/directory found by `find` command
  - `\;`: and of `-exec` option

Comment: If you're calling this from cron, make sure you `cd` to where you need to go; or replace `.` in the find command with an absolute path. I once made this kind of mistake on the job and it took 2 days to restore the machine from backup.

Comment: yes. in cron table replace `.` path by an absolute path - (not a `cd` command)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the answers so far have been shell approaches, here's a tcl one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc delete_syncs {dir} {
    foreach subdir [glob -directory $dir -types d -nocomplain *] {
        delete_syncs $subdir
        set sync [file join $subdir .sync] ;# Or sync or .SYNC or whatever it's actually named
        if {[file exists $sync]} {
            file delete -force -- $sync
        }
    }
}
foreach basedir $argv {
    delete_syncs $basedir
}
```

Takes the base directory (Or directories) to scan as command line arguments.